# BeautifulSoup fails to parse nested <p> elements

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Dependencies:
BeautifulSoup==3.2.1

```
In: from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
In: BeautifulSoup('<p><p>123</p></p>')
Out: <p></p><p>123</p>
```

Why are the two adjacent tags not in the output?

Comment: Beacuse that is not valid HTML. `p`s can't be nested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is just BS3's parser fixing your [broken html](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1).

> The P element represents a paragraph. It cannot contain block-level
>   elements (including P itself).

Answer (score 2):

This

```
<p><p>123</p></p>
```

is not valid HTML. `p`s can't be nested. BS tries to clean it up.

When BS encounters the second `<p>` it thinks the first `p` is finished, so it inserts a closing `</p>`. The second  `</p>` in your input then does not match an opening `<p>` so it is removed.

Answer (score 2):

This is because `BeautifulSoup` has this [`NESTABLE_TAGS`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#Customizing%20the%20Parser) concept/setting:

> When Beautiful Soup is parsing a document, it keeps a stack of open
>   tags. Whenever it sees a new start tag, it tosses that tag on top of
>   the stack. But before it does, it might close some of the open tags
>   and remove them from the stack. Which tags it closes depends on the
>   qualities of tag it just found, and the qualities of the tags in the
>   stack.
>
> So when Beautiful Soup encounters a `<P>` tag, it closes and pops all
>   the tags up to and including the previously encountered tag of the
>   same type. This is the default behavior, and this is how
>   BeautifulStoneSoup treats every tag. It's what you get when a tag is
>   not mentioned in either NESTABLE_TAGS or RESET_NESTING_TAGS. It's also
>   what you get when a tag shows up in RESET_NESTING_TAGS but has no
>   entry in NESTABLE_TAGS, the way the `<P>` tag does.

```
>>> pprint(BeautifulSoup.NESTABLE_TAGS)
{'bdo': [],
 'blockquote': [],
 'center': [],
 'dd': ['dl'],
 'del': [],
 'div': [],
 'dl': [],
 'dt': ['dl'],
 'fieldset': [],
 'font': [],
 'ins': [],
 'li': ['ul', 'ol'],
 'object': [],
 'ol': [],
 'q': [],
 'span': [],
 'sub': [],
 'sup': [],
 'table': [],
 'tbody': ['table'],
 'td': ['tr'],
 'tfoot': ['table'],
 'th': ['tr'],
 'thead': ['table'],
 'tr': ['table', 'tbody', 'tfoot', 'thead'],
 'ul': []}
```

As a workaround, you can allow `p` tag to be inside `p`:

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
>>> BeautifulSoup.NESTABLE_TAGS['p'] = ['p']
>>> BeautifulSoup('<p><p>123</p></p>')
<p><p>123</p></p>
```

Also, `BeautifulSoup` 3rd version is no longer maintained - you should switch to [`BeautifulSoup4`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

When using `BeautifulSoup4`, you can change the underlying [parser](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) to change the behavior:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> BeautifulSoup('<p><p>123</p></p>')
<html><body><p></p><p>123</p></body></html>
>>> BeautifulSoup('<p><p>123</p></p>', 'html.parser')
<p><p>123</p></p>
>>> BeautifulSoup('<p><p>123</p></p>', 'xml')
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<p><p>123</p></p>
>>> BeautifulSoup('<p><p>123</p></p>', 'html5lib')
<html><head></head><body><p></p><p>123</p><p></p></body></html>
```